# .each(function () not working for float values

Tags: javascript, jquery

The output should be `543.54` but I am getting `542.00`. Please help me fix what have I done wrong. Thank you in Advance.

```js
function getTotal() {
  var gtotal = 0.00;
  $(".sub_total").each(function() {
    subtotal = $(this).html() | 0;
    gtotal = parseFloat(gtotal) + parseFloat(subtotal);
  });
  var gtotal = gtotal.toFixed(2);
  $(".grand_total").html(gtotal);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub_total">267.33</div>
<div class="sub_total"></div>
<div class="sub_total">252.55</div>
<div class="sub_total">23.66</div>
<div class="grand_total"></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getTotal()">Sum</a>
```

Comment: `$(this).html() | 0;` => `+$(this).html() || 0;`

Comment: Try `console.log`'ing the value of `subtotal` on each loop iteration. Also, you don't need to `parseFloat(gtotal)`; it's already a float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're using a bitwise OR operator, not a *logical* OR operator.

Note that you can tidy up the logic by using `+=` to increment the `gtotal`, joining the last two lines in to one, and using unobtrusive event handlers instead of the ugly `on*` event attribute:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#sum').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var gtotal = 0.00;

    $(".sub_total").each(function() {
      subtotal = $(this).html() || 0; // note || here
      gtotal += parseFloat(subtotal);
    });

    $(".grand_total").html(gtotal.toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub_total">267.33</div>
<div class="sub_total"></div>
<div class="sub_total">252.55</div>
<div class="sub_total">23.66</div>
<div class="grand_total"></div>
<a href="#" id="sum">Sum</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You take a [bitwise OR `|`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR) instead of a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) for a default value.

The bitwise OR converts to a 32bit integer value and performs an OR operation with the values.

```js
function getTotal() {
  var gtotal = 0;                    // 0
  $(".sub_total").each(function() {
    subtotal = +$(this).html() || 0; // default value
    gtotal = gtotal + subtotal;      // no need to convert numbers again to numbers
  });
  var gtotal = gtotal.toFixed(2);
  $(".grand_total").html(gtotal);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub_total">267.33</div>
<div class="sub_total"></div>
<div class="sub_total">252.55</div>
<div class="sub_total">23.66</div>
<div class="grand_total"></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getTotal()">Sum</a>
```

Comment: `+$(this).html() || 0;` or `Number($(this).html()) || 0;`